# Why doesnt peer-checked/{name} react?

Tags: html, css, radio-button, tailwind-css

Peer-checked not working, when using peer/{name}

[what im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7UvB.png)

You can find the code here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

I tried basically that.

[My code looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNfKx.png)

```
<div class="inline-flex items-center p-2 rounded-md cursor-pointer text-gray-800">
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="toggle" class="peer/draft" checked />
    <label htmlFor="radio1" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-1-md bg-gray-300 peer-checked/draft:bg-violet-400">Monthly</label>
    <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="toggle" class="peer/published" />
    <label htmlFor="radio2" class="px-4 py-2 rounded-1-md bg-gray-300 peer-checked/published:bg-violet-400">Anually</label>
</div>
```

I dont see, why it isnt working.

It always looks like this:
[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHQJA.png)

Does someone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Check Tailwind version - to use labelled classes it should be 3.1+ I believe

Comment: Thank you. Got it working again. The problem was, that somehow Tailwind was not correctly installed.